# An Interpolation inequality in Holder spaces

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am doing some reading about Schauder Estimates. However, I got stuck at this interpolation inequality:  For every $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists $Q(\epsilon)$ such that for all $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(B(0,1))$
\begin{equation}
||u||_{C^2(B(0,1))}\le \epsilon ||u||_{C^{2,\alpha}(B(0,1))}+Q(\epsilon)||u||_{L^2(B(0,1))}
\end{equation}
Can anyone please give  me some hints to prove this inequality ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: Notice that $C^{2,\alpha} $ is compactly embedded in $C^2$ which in turn embeds in $L^2$. Argue by contradiction using this compactness (It's a purely functional analytic thing and it uses nothing special about the spaces).

Comment: I am sorry. But I still can not get it.

Answer (score 4):

@Jose27 has the right idea; proceed by way of contradiction. Assume there exists $\alpha\in (0,1)$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that for every possible choice of $Q$, the estimate fails for some $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(B(0,1))$. So for each integer $Q=k$ there exists $u_k \in C^{2,\alpha}(B(0,1))$ such that

$$\|u_k\|_{C^2} > \epsilon\|u_k\|_{C^{2,\alpha}} + k\|u_k\|_{L^2}.$$

Use the compact embeddings to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: I am wondering if this $Q$ computable or not as it comes from contradiction.